# i am trying to perform outer join

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to join perform outer join and get the error at

> Use an outer join to get comments from users who have not posted about anorexia/obesity.

I also use `.set_index` in the join but it gives me an error at the line:

```
neither_df = neither_df[neither_df['author_right'].isnull()]
```

Full code

```
from tqdm import tqdm

csv_filename = 'full_data_preprocessed.csv'
chunksize = 10000
count = 0
obesity_author_data_frames = []
anorexia_author_data_frames = []
neither_author_data_frames = []

anorexia_record_count = 0
obesity_record_count = 0
neither_record_count = 0

for chunk in tqdm(pd.read_csv(csv_filename, chunksize=chunksize)):
    chunk['author'] = chunk['author'].apply(lambda a : hashlib.md5(a.encode()).hexdigest())
    anorexia_df = anorexia_authors.join(chunk.set_index('author'), on='author', how='inner', lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
    if anorexia_record_count < 10000 and not anorexia_df.empty:
        anorexia_author_data_frames.append(anorexia_df)
        anorexia_record_count += len(anorexia_df)

    obesity_df = obesity_authors.join(chunk.set_index('author'), on='author', how='inner', lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
    if obesity_record_count < 10000 and not obesity_df.empty:
        obesity_author_data_frames.append(obesity_df)
        obesity_record_count += len(obesity_df)

    # Use an outer join to get comments from users who have not posted about anorexia/obesity.
    neither_df = chunk.join(both_authors, on='author', how='outer', lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
    neither_df = neither_df[neither_df['author_right'].isnull()]
    if neither_record_count < 10000 and not neither_df.empty:
        neither_author_data_frames.append(neither_df)
        neither_record_count += len(neither_df)

    count += 1
    if anorexia_record_count > 10000 and obesity_record_count > 10000 and neither_record_count > 10000:
        break
```

which gives the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-889852dca9af> in <module>
     25 
     26     # Use an outer join to get comments from users who have not posted about anorexia/obesity.
---> 27     neither_df = chunk.join(both_authors, on='author', how='outer', lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
     28     neither_df = neither_df[neither_df['author_right'].isnull()]
     29     if neither_record_count < 10000 and not neither_df.empty:

c:\users\nimal\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in join(self, other, on, how, lsuffix, rsuffix, sort)
   7207         """
   7208         return self._join_compat(
-> 7209             other, on=on, how=how, lsuffix=lsuffix, rsuffix=rsuffix, sort=sort
   7210         )
   7211 

c:\users\nimal\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _join_compat(self, other, on, how, lsuffix, rsuffix, sort)
   7230                 right_index=True,
   7231                 suffixes=(lsuffix, rsuffix),
-> 7232                 sort=sort,
   7233             )
   7234         else:

c:\users\nimal\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     84         copy=copy,
     85         indicator=indicator,
---> 86         validate=validate,
     87     )
     88     return op.get_result()

c:\users\nimal\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in __init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
    629         # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce
    630         # to avoid incompat dtypes
--> 631         self._maybe_coerce_merge_keys()
    632 
    633         # If argument passed to validate,

c:\users\nimal\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py in _maybe_coerce_merge_keys(self)
   1144                     inferred_right in string_types and inferred_left not in string_types
   1145                 ):
-> 1146                     raise ValueError(msg)
   1147 
   1148             # datetimelikes must match exactly
```

```
ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat
```

Answer (score 0):

The error implies that the column you are trying to use as the column to join on (author) has different data type in every table - the first (chunk) is a string and the second (both_authors) is an int.
You should convert the type of the first dataframe's column in one of the following ways:

```
chunk['author']=chunk['author'].astype(int)
```

Or:

```
chunk.author.astype(int)
```

Comment: When I use this it also give error which is...……………………...………...…...……...…. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '49d264a69d92ec57c908cdb64cb30931'

Comment: I aslo tried both_authors.set_index('authors') for join and it gives error : KEYERROR...author_right Then I tried merge and it also give error       KEYERROR...…...author_right

Comment: Make sense as this data is indeed not int as I first thought but string. Therefore you need to convert the int type to string. Try this one: `both_authors.author.astype(int)`

Comment: I am already converting the chunk and both_author into hexadecimal

Comment: `import hashlib

anorexia_authors = anorexiaSubreddits.drop_duplicates(subset="author")['author'].apply(lambda a : hashlib.md5(a.encode()).hexdigest()).to_frame()
obesity_authors = obesitySubreddits.drop_duplicates(subset="author")['author'].apply(lambda a : hashlib.md5(a.encode()).hexdigest()).to_frame()
both_authors = bothSubreddits.drop_duplicates(subset="author")['author'].apply(lambda a : hashlib.md5(a.encode()).hexdigest()).to_frame() `

Comment: `chunk['author'] = chunk['author'].apply(lambda a : hashlib.md5(a.encode()).hexdigest())`

Comment: neither_df = neither_df[neither_df['author_right'].isnull()]    issue is basically with this and I don't know what